# how i can remove item from multiple array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array

i have function to remove item in multiple array angularjs. i use a factory like bellow

```
app.factory("array_obj", function () {
       var currentUserIDs = {};
       currentUserIDs.data = [];
       currentUserIDs.city = [];
       return currentUserIDs;

       });
```

in controller have a function like this

```
$scope.deleteItem = function (index) {
                        currentUserIDs.city.splice(index, 1);
                         setUserID(); //insert data in url realtime
                    }
```

this work just for one array like **city**

i need a function to delete any item in **array_obj**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function simpleController($scope) {
    $scope.data = { 
       "results1": [ { "id": 1, "name": "Test" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Beispiel" }, { "id": 3, "name": "Sample" } ] ,
       

"results2": [ { "id": 1, "name": "Test2" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Beispiel2" }, { "id": 3, "name": "Sample2" } ] 

}
    ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app>
    
    <body ng-controller="simpleController">
      <div data-ng-repeat="results in data">
           <div data-ng-repeat="result in results">>
             
             {{result.name}}</br>
           </div> 
        </div> 
  
  </body>

</html>
```

Have Fun..!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
$scope.all_results = data.results1.concat(data.results2);
```

In your view

```
<whatever ng-repeat="item in all_results">{{ item.id }} - {{ item.name }}</whatever>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work with an extra `<div>` with `ng-repeat` attribute in your HTML where in my example results is your data.

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="result in results">
        <div ng-repeat="item in result">{{item.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok this work ... i have function to remove item in  multiple array angularjs. i use a factory like bellow

```
app.factory("array_obj", function () {
       var currentUserIDs = {};
       currentUserIDs.data = [];
       currentUserIDs.city = [];
       return currentUserIDs;

       });
```

in controller have a function like this

```
$scope.deleteItem = function (index) {
                        currentUserIDs.city.splice(index, 1);
                         setUserID(); //insert data in url realtime
                    }
```

this work just for one array like **city**

i need a function to delete any item in **array_obj**